# Task not serializable error when applying regex transformation to String column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I want to reformat a DataFrame's String column. From format

```
(p:str_1,1)(p:str_2,2) ...
```

to format

```
str_1:1|str_2:2 ...
```

I wrote the following code [2] but I get `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable` exception caused by `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator` [3].

Can someone help understand why `Regex$MatchIterator` is not serializable and also how to fix this, it seems that the `Iterator` returned by the `findAllIn(xs)` is causing harm at the for-statement's `elem <- mi` [1].

Thanks a lot!

-- β

[1] If I change `elem <- mi` to use a random iterator (e.g. `elem <- Iterator(1, 2, 3)`) then no compile error and the code runs - but obviously doesn't do what I need it to do. I also tried to get a normal iterator `findAllIn(xs).toIterator` but the same exception occurs.

[2] Code

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(("(p:some_string,6)(p:some_other_string,4)", "foo"), ("(p:yet_another_string,1) ", "bar"))).toDF("my_p", "my_s")

val regexStr: String = "\\((?:p|p2)?:(?<q>.+?),(?<s>\\d+)\\)"
def _reformat(xs: String): String = {
    val re: scala.util.matching.Regex = regexStr.r
    val mi = re.findAllIn(xs)

    val d: Iterator[String] = for {
        elem <- mi
        val q: String = mi.group(1)
        val s: String = mi.group(2)
        val pair: String = s"${q}:${s}"
    } yield pair
    d.mkString("|")
}
def reformat: UserDefinedFunction = udf[String, String](_reformat)

val dfReformated: DataFrame = df
    .withColumn("my_p", reformat($"my_p"))
```

[3] StackTrace

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2039)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsWithIndex$1.apply(RDD.scala:817)
  ...
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:1934)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2149)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:239)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:526)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:506)
  ... 46 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator
Serialization stack:
  - object not serializable (class: scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator, value: empty iterator)
  - field (class: $iw, name: mi, type: class scala.util.matching.Regex$MatchIterator)
  - object (class $iw, $iw@79303206)
  - field (class: $iw, name: $iw, type: class $iw)
  ...
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using spark 2.1.1

Comment: You mean that the code runs without problem with Spark 2.1.1?

Comment: yes, but I can reproduce your exception if I define `val mi = re.findAllIn(xs)` outside of  `_reformat`.

Comment: Interesting. That is already a good datapoint, thanks! I am using Spark 2.0.2. I will try to upgrade to a cluster with more recent Spark